# PySide installation fail on windows with Python 2.7 "ImportError: No module named _vendor"

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, pip, pyside

following error occurs when i try to do `pip install -U PySide`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip2.7.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\pip.py", line 17466, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "C:\Python27\pip.py", line 17436, in bootstrap
    cert.write(pkgutil.get_data("pip._vendor.requests", "cacert.pem"))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 570, in get_data
    loader = get_loader(package)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 456, in get_loader
    return find_loader(fullname)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 466, in find_loader
    for importer in iter_importers(fullname):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 422, in iter_importers
    __import__(pkg)
ImportError: No module named _vendor
```

simply giving `pip` command will cause this error. My python related environment variables are set properly but no luck. here they are

```
PYTHONHOME=C:\Python27
PYTHONPATH=C:\Python27\Lib
```

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Hi, what is your pip version ? Please follow the pyside install instruction and if possible install latest version of pip which has built-in wheel support: http://pyside.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/windows.html#installing-prerequisites

Comment: @rlacko I got pip from the link you mentioned. I am already following PySide installation instructions. Not sure where am i missing !

Comment: What is your pip version ? Check if you have _vendor module on this path c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip\\_vendor.

Comment: @rlacko Yes i do have !

Comment: Even just giving `pip` command will cause this error

Comment: Ok, you have broken pip. How is it related to pyside ? You should first fix the pip problem, than try to install pyside.

Comment: @rlacko I am not aware with `pip` I just follwoed `PySide` installation instructions. Also I have mentioned it already in my question.

Comment: I had newer issues with pip when using official python downloaded from python.org. how did you install python ? looks like your python installation is broken ? I would like to see your python related environment variables.

Comment: I just got this from a box with the latest 2.7.9 python, latest virtual env, latest setuptools and latest pip installed.  Machine is not Internet connected.

Comment: I have same problem. Any ideas how to fix it?